# Как копировать в буфер куски текста размером больше одного экрана в Midnight Commander на Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mc

Не использую Putty, запускаю MC напрямую из терминала Ubuntu.

В режиме просмотра текстового файла (по F3) могу выделить кусок текста, который помещается в экран, зажав шифт и левую кнопку мыши.
Однако, не могу найти способ выделения куска текста, который уже не помещается в один экран. При зажатом шифте и левой клавиши мыши, скролл просто перестает работать.

Как можно решить проблему выделения/копирования больших кусков текста из режима просмотра?

Comment: Прямого способа что-то скопировать из `mc` на несколько экранов я не знаю, но могу предложить другой вариант: воспользоваться встроенным редактором (F4, mcedit), в нем выделить нужный кусок  через нажатия F3 (один раз - начало блока, второй - конец блока) и потом сохранить выделенный блок в отдельный файл (F9->Файл->Копировать в файл->Можно указать свое имя файла). А уже потом этот файл можно вставить куда нужно (либо вывести на терминал через `cat` и уже оттуда скопировать средствами терминала).

Comment: Перестать пользоваться `mc`, очевидно.

Comment: @Vladimir спасибо за идею, но файл слишком большой, и не открывается в режимер редактирования. Пришлось возиться с grep-ом

Comment: @0andriy к сожалению сервер удалённый, и прав на установку другого по нет, приходится использовать то, что есть.

Comment: В свой домашний каталог можно притащить всё что угодно.

Comment: Скачайте файл себе и работайте с ним через локальный редактор. Тем более если он слишком большой для mcedit.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов - перейти с mc на [far2l](https://github.com/elfmz/far2l). Там поддерживается полноценный буфер обмена, можно классическими Ctrl/Shift+Ins/Del пользоваться во встроенном редакторе.

Comment: Это не решает вопрос с Midnight Commander. См. обсуждение «[**Уход от проблемы вместо её решения**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3404/199934)». Спасибо.